# How can I get an animation with GraphPlot?

Tags: animation, plot, julia

I want to make an animation of networks(graphs) with [GraphPlot](https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/LightGraphs.jl).

In Julia, in order to have an animation, we usually use Plot like

```
@gif for i=1:100
    plot(...)
end
```

But when I tried to make an animation of network, I got an error.

```
No current plot/subplot
```

What I want to have is the simple animation such that node colors are changed over time, and the code is like this:

```
using Plot
gr()
using GraphPlot

path = PathGraph(5)
nodecolor = [colorant"lightseagreen", colorant"orange"]
label=ones(Int, 5)
@gif for t in 1:5
    nodefillc = nodecolor[label]
    gplot(path, nodefillc=nodefillc)
    label[t]=2
end
```

I think @gif(or @animation) cannot be applied to GraphPlot.

Is there anyone who knows the way to make an animation of graphs with GraphPlot?